# Jquery how to pass object to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Hello Guys can I just pass the object to another jquery function like the below ?

```
$('#course_id').on('change', function(e){
    var cour_id = e.target.value;

    $.get('/ajax-classification?cour_id=' + cour_id, function(data){

        console.log(data);
        $('#classification_id').empty();
        $('#classification_id').append('<option value="">--Select Classification--</option>');
        $.each(data, function(index, classificationObj){
            $('#classification_id').append('<option value="'+
                classificationObj.classification_id+'">'+ 
                classificationObj.classification_name+'</option>');
        });
    });

    //Here i want this function can get back the classificationObj.
    $('#classification_id').on('change', function(e){
        var cour_id = "1";
        var classi_id = e.target.value;
        $.get('/ajax-classification-index?classi_id=' + classi_id +'&cour_id='+ cour_id, function(data1){
            console.log(data1);
            $('#classification_index').empty();
            $('#classification_index').append('<option value="">--Select Index--</option>');
            $.each(data1, function(index, classificationIndexObj){
                $('#classification_index').append('<option value="">'+ 
                    classificationIndexObj.classification_index+'</option>');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

What should I do? How can I modify the first or second Jquery function?

Comment: You need to use a variable whose scope is outside the two functions.

Comment: What should happen if the user changes the second element before they change the first element?

Comment: Thankyou for your quick reply sir!  I have updated my code. The object is received from another page. Actually this part of code is like a 3-level dependent dropdown. There're Course-Classificaiton-Classification_index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.data()` to save the object with each option.

```
    $.each(data, function(index, classificationObj){
        $('#classification_id').append($("<option>", {
            value: classificationObj.classification_id,
            text: classificationObj.classification_name,
            data: { object: classificationOBj }
        }));
    });
```

Then in the `#classification_id` change handler you can use:

```
var classificationObj = $(this).find("option:selected").data("object");
```

Comment: GOD LIKE !!  You Are Awesome!